# (Python) Just easy incrementing variable that i can't solve

Tags: python, variables

I'm working on a project and now i'm stuck.
I've tried to search but I didn't find anything, maybe because I don't know what I have to search exactly.

the part that I can't figure out is the same at this one

```
bum = 0

def tryit():
    for bum in range(5):
        print("Hey")
        bum += 1
    print(bum)

tryit()
tryit()
tryit()
```

I want the output to be

```
hey
hey
hey
hey
hey
5
hey
hey
hey
hey
hey
10  
hey
hey
hey
hey
hey
15
```

instead, the output is

```
hey
hey
hey
hey
hey
5
hey
hey
hey
hey
hey
5  
hey
hey
hey
hey
hey
5
```

how can i keep increment the variable bum ?

i know that maybe is stupid and sorry but i really can't figure out

Answer (score 2):

Change bum to a global variable so your function can access it. Also, I would recommend changing your for loop variable to reduce any confusion.

**Code:**

```
bum = 0
def tryit():
    global bum
    for i in range(5):
        print("Hey")
        bum += 1
    print(bum)
```

**Output:**

[image]

This was for demonstration purposes only. While a global variable was used for this example it is typically not recommended as it can have negative side effects in a real world scenario. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil).

Comment: @fobu36 if I answered your question please mark it as the answer so that others in the future can benefit as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In for loop, you should use different variable name rather than bum in for statement.

Second, maybe you need global keyword in tryit() for bum

Answer (score 0):

You're shadowing a global name but using the one in the `for` loop scope. Instead, use two different names for the `bum` outside of the function, and the `bum` inside the for loop.